# How to tell jenkins not to kill processes after successful execution of job in multijob project?

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins **multijob project**.

**In 1st phase**, I start databases and build core part.

sample shell command to start Mongodb:

```
/root/software/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.3/bin/mongod&
```

**In 2nd phase**, I have various jobs to build some clients.

After 1st phase job, after starting servers and building core part. I see logs-

```
Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
2016-08-26T20:23:00.815+0530 [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2016-08-26T20:23:00.833+0530 [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2016-08-26T20:23:00.879+0530 [signalProcessingThread] dbexit: 
2016-08-26T20:23:00.903+0530 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2016-08-26T20:23:00.903+0530 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 7
2016-08-26T20:23:00.903+0530 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 8
2016-08-26T20:23:00.903+0530 [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
Finished: SUCCESS
```

This is stopping all the databases and build is failing for phase2 jobs.

How to tell jenkins not to kill processes after a job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs shared by @jayan,

You can disable **killing processes spawned by a job during a build** by setting a Java property named `hudson.util.ProcessTree.disable` to the value `true`.

This can be done as a parameter to the "java" binary when starting Jenkins:

```
 java -Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true -jar jenkins.war
```

Comment: Why it doesn't work for me? only change the BUILD_ID works

Answer (score 16):

Jenkins uses a special mechanism to cleanup child processes.  It looks for process with `BUILD_ID` matching the build number. You can set that to different value and jenkins will skip killing the process.

From the docs:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe /your/mongodb/process
```

or for pipelines:

```
JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe /your/mongodb/process
```

Comment: This was a simple fix for a 2-step build/test step where the build was being killed before the tests executed. We just do the cleanup of the previous build before the next one starts. This worked perfectly thanks!

Comment: Whatever happened to this ProcessTreeKiller plugin now? That link in this answer is broken now. I guess that plugin is no longer available for use.

Comment: It is not a "plugin" ; stop jobs and not stopping job as needed is  jenkins core feature.

Answer (score 3):

Any one facing the same problem and using pipeline project, set `JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE` instead of `BUILD_ID`.

Dont waste your time setting `HUDSON_COOKIE`, `HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE`, `JENKINS_COOKIE` or `JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE`. None of them work for pipeline project.

Refer to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28182 for more details.

Source: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/running-a-background-process-in-pipeline-job/1513#1513

Answer (score 2):

First, update your manual start or stop command inside a shell script and use the following line in your Jenkins pipeline script.

```
sh script: "export JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe && sh script.sh"
```