# jenkins build report is success but the site cannot be reach

Tags: jenkins, next.js

These are my jenkins execute shell commands to build a nextjs hello world app and deploy in my local machine in a different directory.
[jenkins shell command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmFvJ.png)
[This is the console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjywC.png)

[this is the ecosystem config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nAJw.png)

http://localhost:3000/ , the site cannot be reached

I tried without the pm2, if i dont send the process to background i can access the site but whenever i send it to background with & or nohup or pm2 the site cannot  be reached. What should i do solve this problem

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Jenkins terminates any processes created by the build when the build is complete. This includes your `pm2` command. You can read about this in detail [in the docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/spawning-processes/). A [workaround](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/spawning-processes/#workarounds) is also mentioned in the docs, which in your case would be something like:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
```

Also, look through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39169457/3730626).